# Can anyone provide a working example of an AWS SAM template that has CORS setup in a HttpApi resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-sam, aws-http-api

I have been going round and round trying to get this working. I want to be able to define the `CorsConfiguration` in the **HttpApi** resource definition but everything I try simply doesn't work. I can only get CORS working if I defined it globally, but that only works if I don't define the HttpApi resource.

The following is what i have so far based on the documentation.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app
  
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:

  MainApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless:HttpApi
    Properties:
      CorsConfiguration:
        AllowHeaders:
          - "*"
        AllowMethods:
          - "GET"
        AllowOrigins:
          - "http://localhost:8000"
        ExposeHeaders:
          - "*"
      DefinitionBody:
        openapi: 3.0.1
        info:
          title: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        paths: {}

  CheckHumanFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        CheckHuman:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref MainApi
            Path: /human-check
            Method: post
    Metadata:
      DockerTag: nodejs16.x-v1
      DockerContext: ./api/human-check
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Outputs:
  MainApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  CheckHumanFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt CheckHumanFunction.Arn
  CheckHumanFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for CheckHuman function"
    Value: !GetAtt CheckHumanFunctionIamRole.Arn
```

The result of this is a 403 on the OPTIONS (preflight) request.

Please can someone provide a working example? But I cannot find an actual working example anywhere and the documentation is infuriating!

Help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 1):

1. You should add `POST` and `OPTIONS` to **AllowMethods**:

```yaml
CorsConfiguration
  AllowMethods:
    - GET
    - POST
    - OPTIONS
```

This will cover the preflight request needs.

2. Note a typo error in your HTTP API resource type definition (has to be `AWS::Serverless::HttpApi`)

This [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/configuring-cors-on-amazon-api-gateway-apis/) works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using to configure CORS for my HttpApi (note: I'm using this with a Cognito Authorizer):

```yaml
    Resources:
      ApiGatewayApi:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
        Properties:
          StageName: Prod
          DefaultRouteSettings:
            ThrottlingBurstLimit: 5
            ThrottlingRateLimit: 20
          Auth:
            Authorizers:
              GeneralAuth:
                AuthorizationScopes:
                  - email
                IdentitySource: "$request.header.Authorization"
                JwtConfiguration:
                  issuer: !Sub https://cognito-idp.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${UserPoolId}
                  audience:
                    - !Ref Audience
          CorsConfiguration:
            AllowMethods:
              - GET
            AllowOrigins:
              - http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I used https://cors.serverlessland.com/ to generate my AWS::Serverless::HttpApi cors configuration and it magically started working. Maybe I had a whitespace issue in yaml, I don't know.